# Javascript/jQuery scrollTop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I've re-created a simple version of what I'm trying to do [here (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/jNeAP/)

The header should stay where it is, and as you scroll down, when you click the header div it should scroll back up to the top, which it does. But if you focus on the input, or click the "logo", the scroll should stay where it is.

With the first method I've tried is by using jQuery's `.css` and setting the input/logo's `z-index` as higher than the header, then getting the current scroll and keeping it at that position.

This sort of works, but once you click the input or logo, the header scroll no longer works.

I've also tried changing the logo/input jQuery to `.animate` with a slow speed, and it stays static for a couple seconds and then scrolls to the top even though I've not set it to do so. Here is the second example - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/NkRRJ/)

Doing it with the second example however doesn't stop the other function from working.

Is there any reason for this behaviour that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the click event from propagating to the header.

```
$("#logo, #input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this interesting [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) about event order, all you have to do is stop propagation. Here your modified [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gPDtC/)

```
$("#logo, #input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var y = window.scrollY;

    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: y
    }, 'slow');
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: y
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is stop the propegation of the event.  To do this you return false from your click function.

```
$("#logo, #input").click(function() {
    return false;  // Add this line
});
```

Here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/BRnvT/

Comment: I believe this will also render all clicks within the container useless as well, which may pose a problem for the OP.

Comment: Steve's answer is more appropriate.  My solution also adds e.preventDefault() which is not ideal if the logo was a link.  You can read more at
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: This does work but like you've pointed out the logo is a link in the real version which would render it useless for navigation, so `stopPropagation` is more appropriate for what I want, but still thank you for the answer :)